# I cant edit my mesh material with shader editor

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm not sure how to explain it but I think that's how you do, here's a video to my problem. I would appreciate some help.

video:
https://streamable.com/prfg5g

blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2ncijj7t8uj5qolv0lerq/shmacked.blend?rlkey=mtbicnsvi03mlppzs461vjczr&dl=0

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your *Viewport Shading* to *Material preview* (or render).

<kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, I was so confused lol.